# Pattern attribute simply not working in HTML form

Tags: html, validation, design-patterns, attributes, deprecated

```html
      <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Form practice</title>
   </head>
    <body><h1>Register</h1>

 <form>
  <label for="first name">First Name</label>
  <input id="first name" type="text" name="first name" placeholder="John" required>


  <label for="last name">Last Name</label>
  <input id="last name" type="text" name="last name" placeholder="Smith" required>

  <div>
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="male">

  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input id="female" type="radio" name="gender" value="female">

  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <input id="other" type="radio" name="gender" value="other">
  </div>

  <div>
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="your email">

      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password" id="password" pattern=".{5,10}" title="5 to 8 characters" required>
  </div>

  <div>
   <label>
    Birthday:
    <select name="month">
     <option>Month</option>
     <option>Jan</option>
     <option>Feb</option>
     <option>Mar</option>
    </select>
    <select month="day">
     <option>Day</option>
     <option>01</option>
     <option>02</option>
     <option>03</option>
    </select>
    <select month="year">
     <option>Year</option>
     <option>1990</option>
     <option>1991</option>
     <option>1992</option>
    </select>
   </label>
  </div>

  <div>
   <label for="agreed">I agree to the terms and conditions</label>
   <input id="agreed" type="checkbox" name="agreed">
  </div>

     <input type="submit" name="">
  </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The pattern attribute in the input tag for the password is not working, neither is the title attribute.　Only the required attribute is working. 
I have tried checking in Chrome and Safari.
Is it deprecated?
In what other way can I add a validation for minimum length (aside from using JS)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the problem is. I copy-pasted your code and it works fine on my end, unless I'm misinterpreting your question. Can you explain the issue you are having further? I tested it in both Chrome and Firefox:

[image: password min/max characters]

and the title:

[image]